# R Loop optimisation/ Loop is way too time consuming

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, time, data.table

The following loop takes ages. Is there any way to this in a more time-efficient way? The following data.table consists of 27 variables and more than 600k observations.

```
data <- read.table("file.txt", header = T, sep= "|")
colnames(data)[c(1)] <- c("X")
data <- as.data.table(data)
n=1;
vector <- vector()
for(i in 2:nrow(data))
{
  if(data[["X"]][i] != data[["X"]][i-1])
  {
   n=1; vector[i]=1} 
 else {
   n=n+1; vector[i]=n}}
```

Basically, I need to index every appearance of a unique entry in X, i.e. the first time it appeared, the second time it appeared, etc and then merge this to the existing data as additional column. However, I got stock at compiling the vector.

Thank you.

Comment: a more time consuming way?

Comment: Where is `vector` initiated?

Comment: also where is `n` initiated...

Comment: I think you want something like `data[, v := rowid(X)]`. Hard to visualize the problem when you give no example data and edit a "vector" that is not first created.

Comment: My bad, just copied and pasted part of the script... Edited now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, use `fread`:

```
DT <- fread("file.txt", sep = "|")
```

Next, use `setnames`:

```
setnames(DT, 1, "X")
```

Finally, use `rowid`:

```
DT[ , vector := rowid(X)]
```